# Magento2 : Top Header file location in Luma theme

Tags: magento2, header-files

I created a custom theme from LUMA, and I want to remove/Edit Top header which is in gray bar.

How can I remove the gray bar from the theme? Where is the file located for the top header? I want to remove this gray bar and add custom div here.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

just add `remove="false"` to `referenceContainer` to remove that gray panel.

---

path - ProjectName/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

---

Look screenshot of code

[image: look screenshot of code]

Answer (score 0):

inside 
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Customer\templates\account\link\authorization.phtml

Comment: I need file where this full gray div exist. Please help

Comment: if you have your custom theme then follow path app/design\Vendor\Theme\Magento_theme\view\frontend\templates\html\header.phtml or else to get this file from app/vendor/magento/module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\header.phtml